# Selenium Webdriver Python find next element

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have this HTML code:

```
<caption>
    <em id="qwerty"> ABC </em>
</caption>

<caption>
    <em id="qwerty"> 123 </em>
</caption>
```

How can I make a program in Python with Selenium Webdriver that finds the second element with id="qwerty"?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out, that two elements with the same `id` attribute on one page is a defect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find_elements_by_id()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_id) and take the second element (indexing in python starts from 0):

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_id('qwerty')[1]
```

Comment: If I have a parent web element, how I use this to find the next element?